# "inserting on the radius"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand this sentence. What do they mean by "inserting on the radius"?

> Unlike the biceps, the brachialis does not **insert on the radius**, and does not participate in pronation and supination of the forearm.

Comment: Hint: look for points of attachment for muscles and tendons. https://www.sports-health.com/glossary/muscle-insertion

Comment: Note: 'radius' here is not a line from the centre of a circle to its circumference; it's a bone in the arm.

Answer (score 1):

Radius being the bone, so inserting on the radius would be either touching or connected to the radius.

Comment: Note that one definition of "insert (from Lexico) is : *in Anatomy•Zoology*
"(of a muscle or other organ) be attached to a part, especially that which is moved."
*"the muscle that raises the wing is inserted on the dorsal surface of the humerus"*

Comment: @DavidSiegel Lexico is shut down

Comment: @Sergey My error, the def is from [Oxford languages](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=insert+definition)